# Curl - Invalid params null

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I tried to make a script to post a request every time travis-ci build is finished.

I got this error: `Invalid params null, 1668, https://github.com/HyperiumClient/Hyperium/releases/download/1668./build/libs/Hyperium-0.24.jar:1`

Code: https://gist.github.com/Cubxity/457736a7bcbfe6d6f3ae2a5db04c0806

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo -e "WARNING!!\nYou need to pass the WEBHOOK_URL environment variable as the first argument to this script." && exit
fi

echo -e "[Webhook]: Sending webhook to Discord...\\n";

AUTHOR_NAME="$(git log -1 "$TRAVIS_COMMIT" --pretty="%aN")"
COMMITTER_NAME="$(git log -1 "$TRAVIS_COMMIT" --pretty="%cN")"
COMMIT_SUBJECT="$(git log -1 "$TRAVIS_COMMIT" --pretty="%s")"
COMMIT_MESSAGE="$(git log -1 "$TRAVIS_COMMIT" --pretty="%b")"

if [[ $TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST != false ]]; then
  URL="https://github.com/$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG/pull/$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST"
else
  URL=""
fi

TIMESTAMP=$(date --utc +%FT%TZ)
WEBHOOK_DATA='{
  "embeds": [ {
    "color": '3066993',
    "author": {
      "name": "Beta release (Build #'"$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"')",
      "url": "https://travis-ci.org/'"$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG"'/builds/'"$TRAVIS_BUILD_ID"'",
      "icon_url": "https://travis-ci.org/images/logos/TravisCI-Mascot-blue.png"
    },
    "title": "'"$COMMIT_SUBJECT"'",
    "url": "'"$URL"'",
    "description": "'"${COMMIT_MESSAGE//$'\n'/ }"\\n\\n"https://github.com/HyperiumClient/Hyperium/releases/tag/$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"'",
    "timestamp": "'"$TIMESTAMP"'"
  } ]
}'

(curl --fail --progress-bar -A "TravisCI-Webhook" -H Content-Type:application/json -H X-Author:Cubxity#7801 -d "$WEBHOOK_DATA" "$1" \
  && echo -e "\\n[Webhook]: Successfully sent the webhook.") || echo -e "\\n[Webhook]: Unable to send webhook."

FILE_NAME=$(find .| grep Hyperium-):1

curl -d "url=https://github.com/HyperiumClient/Hyperium/releases/download/${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}$FILE_NAME&id=${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}&secret=${SECRET}&beta=true -H Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST https://sk1er.club/user/hyperium_update
```

Travis config: https://github.com/HyperiumClient/Hyperium/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Please don't post links

Comment: Please post the relevant code/config as text here (highlight it after pasting and select the `{}` button or Ctrl+k to preserve whitespace and line feeds). The reason for this is that our Q&A can help people in the future, but if that link dies then the usefulness of the Q&A goes with it.

Comment: @JNevill the link is from github, it's most likely not going down

Comment: I agree. I think it would be interesting bet on whether this question or that github link lives on longer on the internet. We both may be dead before the bet pays off though. Still... pasting relevant code in the Q&A is part and parcel to how SO works. It will also greatly increase your chances of getting an answer here as many folks can't even be bothered to read an entire question, let alone clicking on a link.

Comment: As far as the question is concerned though... toss this thing into shellcheck.net. I believe you have some issues with your single and double quotes where you set that `WEBHOOK_DATA` variable.

Comment: @JNevill the error is in the last line, WEBHOOK_DATA stuff works fine

Comment: Is this an error from curl or the response from your hyperium_update webservice? I couldn't reproduce it using curl/7.52.1

Comment: @TobiasK. i am not sure about that

Comment: @Cubxity: Invoke curl with `-i`, then it will dump response headers. If there ARE response headers above the error then, then it is likely from the webservice.